# How can I prove 1/n is O(1)?

Tags: math, big-o

How can I prove mathematically that 1/n is O(1)? I'm confused on where to start. Any help?

Comment: Did you try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation?

Comment: Start (and end) by proving that `1/n <= 1` for all `n > 1`.

Comment: Are you sure the questions isn't, "prove O(1/n) == O(1)"?

Comment: yeah the question is: use the definition of big oh to prove that 1/n is O(1).

Comment: What algorithm is being used to compute 1/n?

Comment: @user459066: Notation matters.  Proving that O(1/n)==O(1) is not the same as proving 1/n runs in time O(1).   You aren't being precise.  Which is it?

Comment: @IraBaxter how are they different? 1/n is a function so i think they meant the former but idk what u mean by the latter

Answer (score 3):

As the problem says, begin with the definition of big-O notation.

```
F(x) = O(G(x)) IFF there exist constants k and m, 
such that for all n > m, k*|G(n)| > F(n).
```

(Consult your textboox for the precise wording here.)

Informally, this means that if we go far enough "out", eventually G(n) will dominate F(n), no matter how big an initial advantage we give to F(n) via constant factors.

---

So, how do you prove something like this?

Proofs like this are typically done constructively--showing that particular well-chosen values for m and k make the inequality work.

Now you're just doing algebra. Find some m and k that satisfy the formal definition. Depending on the level of formality/detail required, you might need to prove that 1/n is monotonically decreasing (or do some induction proof) to show that your choice of m and k actually works.

---

Margus (and Loadmaster): Asymptotic notation talks about *functions*, and is completely independent of the underlying hardware and implementation. 1/n=O(1) is a mathematical truth that isn't predicated even on the existence of things that we call "computers". If you are thinking about number of instructions, you're reasoning about complexity classes (think P, NP, EXP), not asymptotic notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are demonstrating this for an algorithm, start by pointing that the input will be a positive amount of data (N >= 1), you cannot enter 1/2 data :)

After that, demonstrate that 1/n is a growing function when n > 1, you should use induction on that, and you are good to go, because you already pointed that n will be bigger than 1 always!

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's think about this for a minute. We have two functions f(n)=1/n and g(n)=1. What we need is *two* constants C and k such that 0 <= f(n) <= C*g(n) whenever n > k. If the domain of both functions is restricted to the set of all positive integers, we simply select C=2 and k=0. Then we have 0 <= 1/n <= 2*1 for all n > 0. Here we call C and k the witnesses to the relationship 1/n is O(1).

Need to prove it a bit more rigorously? Well... clearly 1/n < 1 **if and only if** 1 < n (by simple algebra). Hence if n = 1 (which means 1/n = 1) we know that 2*1 > 1 and if n > 1 we know that this implies 1/n < 1, in which case 2*1 > 1/n.

Answer (score -3):

You actually don't have to prove it, it is a fact. the upper bound of of 1/n given n being an natural number larger than 0 is always 1.

Comment: downvoters - It's generally common courtesy to leave a comment explaining *why* you downvoted.
@Tokenized man - I would assume you're being downvoted because the question asks *how* to prove it. It is a "fact" because it already has been proven. The OP just wants to know how to approach proving it himself.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but two possible reasons for a downvote are (1) This answer has already been given, multiple times, and (2) This answer doesn't help the person who asked the question because this question was asked (and answered) ten months ago.